# R passing a function argument to ggplot

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, eval

I'm trying to pass a function argument (or parameter) to a ggplot - here's a dummy dataset to show/ test

```
test <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                   base=c(230,365,390,201,298), 
                   heig=c(200,310,90,100, 91), 
                   widt=c(21,75,22,46,51))

fun1 <- function(va1,va2){
  ggplot(data=test,mapping=aes(va1, va2)) + geom_point()
}

fun1(base,heig)
```

I get an error:

> ```
> Error in `geom_point()`:
> ! Problem while computing aesthetics.
> ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
> Caused by error in `FUN()`:
> ! object 'base' not found
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> ```

I tried `{{}}`, `[[]]` and other combinations inside the ggplot in order to call the function param to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use enquo like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)

fun1 <- function(va1,va2) {
  va1 <- enquo(va1)
  va2 <- enquo(va2)

  ggplot2::ggplot(data=test,mapping=aes(!!va1, !!va2)) + 
    geom_point()
}
```

##### From the help page of the "Tidy eval helpers":

(You can find it with: ?enquo):

> enquo() and enquos() delay the execution of one or several function arguments. The former returns a single expression, the latter returns a list of expressions. Once defused, expressions will no longer evaluate on their own. They must be injected back into an evaluation context with ⁠!!⁠ (for a single expression) and ⁠!!!⁠ (for a list of expressions).

Comment: I'd have attached `rlang` rather than `dplyr`, but it probably doesn't matter:  `ggplot2` forces both to be loaded anyway.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `{{ var }}`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)

fun1 <- function(va1,va2){
  ggplot(data=test, mapping=aes({{va1}}, {{va2}})) + geom_point()
}

fun1(base, heig)
```

[image]

Or using `base::match.call` and `base::eval` (this will change the axes labels):

```r
library(ggplot2)

fun1 <- function(va1,va2){
  arg <- match.call()
  ggplot(data=test, mapping=aes(eval(arg$va1), eval(arg$va2))) + geom_point()
}

fun1(base, heig)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>